# Undefined variable , works in wamp fail in real server

Tags: php, server, wamp

```
    function readDatabase($filename) 
    {
        // read the XML database of aminoacids
        $data = implode("", file($filename));
        $parser = xml_parser_create();
        xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0);
        xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1);
        xml_parse_into_struct($parser, $data, $values, $tags);
        xml_parser_free($parser);

        // loop through the structures
        foreach ($tags as $key=>$val) {
            if ($key == "movie") {
                $movranges = $val;
                // each contiguous pair of array entries are the 
                // lower and upper range for each movie definition
                for ($i=0; $i < count($movranges); $i+=2) {
                    $offset = $movranges[$i] + 1;
                    $len = $movranges[$i + 1] - $offset;
                    $tdb[] = parseMov(array_slice($values, $offset, $len));
                }
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        return $tdb;// <----------------- on xampp works perfectly
                    // on real server 
                    // it returns undefined variable ;(
    }
```

> Blockquote
>       //issue with return $tdb 
>       //undefined variable and is not even an error .... is just a notice
>       //but still won't work on server
>       //when running true xampp it works perfectly

Comment: You'll get that error if there are no "tags" or none of the "tags" have the key of "movie", or none of the "tags" with a key of movies have items.

Comment: In real server probably your  $tags is not valid for foreach so the $tdb vars is undefined  (not setted in foreach)

Comment: Thanks Guys! I go back to poke around with that